# Kivy scrollview with the kivy language and a custom widget

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

I'm using Kivy, a Python Library, and i'm having trouble getting a scroll view to work, and organizing it into a .kv file.

I have a big system that's broken up into many .py and .kv files.

I am also using kivy's screen manager

ui_manager.py

```
#ui_manager.py
class UIManager():
    _ScreenManager = None

    def __init__(self, inScreenManager):
        self.ScreenManager = inScreenManager # The main app constructs the manager, sends to me, then returns it as the root widget.
```

main.py

```
#main.py
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screenManager = ScreenManager()
        uiManager = ui_manager.UIManager(screenManager)
        return screenManager
```

Obviously I ommited a little code, but this is almost exactly what happens.

One of the screns needs to scroll. It will have a long graphic and many buttons.
The Kivy documentation, as usual, only tells me how to do it via code, NOT via the kivy language (.kv files)
http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html

I want a class, OrangeWidget, to hold the scrolling widget, so I can play with its data later on.
Here is my best attempt at getting an organized scrollview working

orange_widget.py

```
#orange_widget.py

class OrangeWidget(Screen):
    pass

class OrangeGraphic(Widget):
    pass
```

Orange.kv

```
<OrangeLineWidget>
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (400, 1200)

        OrangeLineGraphic:
            pos: root.pos

<OrangeGraphic>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, .5, 0, 1       
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 15, 0
            size: 30, self.height * 2
    Label:
        text: "Hello"
```

I know it's a lot, and it's not looking well organized already, but i'm just trying to figure out how to get the dang thing working properly.

Here is the current result: It won't scroll, and for whatever reason it's been "boxed" to the right, instead of taking up the full screen
[image]

Answer (score 2):

as answered on the ML, here you don't define the Label pos, your OrangeGraphic being a simple widget, not a layout, you need to do it:

```
<OrangeGraphic>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, .5, 0, 1       
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 15, 0
            size: 30, self.height * 2
   Label:
        text: "Hello"
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
```

Comment: This works for just setting it to root.pos, keeps it at the very bottom left of the slider, but what about moving the button/label to relative positions? If you did y: root.y / 2, or size_hint=(.5, 1) you're going to get some very messed up behavior

Comment: I'm not sure what messed up behaviour you are talking about, if you put "y: root.y / 2" (you probably want "center_y: root.center_y" but that's not a big difference in that case), the y pos will updated when root.y is updated. For your usage of size_hint, you will just get the child be half the width of the parent, i don't see any issue with that. I understand the RelativeLayout solution is easier, but i think the issue is a misunderstanging of positions and bindings in kivy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the trick, for this particular "sliding" screen, was to use a "Relative Layout"
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/RwuI8QGm3fw

Here is the updated code:
orange_widget.py

```
class OrangeWidget(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OrangeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        scrollView = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1))

        # add custom widget into that layout
        customWidget = OrangeGraphicWidget(height=1200, size_hint_y=None)
        #layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        scrollView.add_widget(customWidget)

        self.add_widget(scrollView)

class OrangeGraphicWidget(RelativeLayout):
    pass
```

OrangeWidget.kv

```
<OrangeWidget>

<OrangeGraphicWidget>
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: 1, .5, 0, 1           
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 15, 20
            size: 30, self.height - (self.height / 10)

    Button:
        text: "Button 1"
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint: (None, None)

    Button:
        text: "Button 2"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .95}
        size_hint: (None, None)
```